# How to prevent removing accessibility focus from a bottom sheet?

Tags: android, android-layout, accessibility, android-view

I need to open a bottom sheet with some content, and I want the accessibility focus to stay in that bottom sheet. I've tried to open the sheet in a view, in a separate fragment, in a PopupWindow, but anyway it was possible to move the focus "bellow" my sheet. Is there any way to solve that?
Thank you.